# How to disable the mute/unmute notification which appears on desktop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, notifications

How do I disable the mute notification which appears on the desktop while pressing the keyboard shortcut mute/unmute button with the name of the artist and the song.

Adding the [Snip](https://ibb.co/Bsx3QZJ) of the notification for your reference. I just don't want it to appear when I press the mute/unmute button.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?  I have seen that extra notification here, but it has disappeared on both my systems. I wonder if it is update related.

Comment: @John Windows 10 Pro, Version 1909, OS buid 18363.1440

Comment: I am at Windows 10 Pro V21H1 . There is no additional notification now. I looked through settings and do not see this extra notification in settings. I will look around again.

Comment: Does this notification pops up when you press the mute button on the keyboard (f6 in my case) as well?

Comment: No. My button is F1 on this X1 ThinkPad and a mechanical button on my X230 ThinkPad.  The notification does not show up on either or on my Desktop machine. I looked at all the audio settings (lower right audio icon) and so far have not found anything.

Comment: When it comes up, see if there is a Close X top right.

Comment: No. It stays for 6 seconds and then disappear. It also shows the name of the artist and the song details when you are listening to a YT video.

Comment: On my machines here, I have determined that it is a function of the website. It does show up in You Tube

Comment: Thanks John, it worked for me when I use this in both chrome as well as Edge. "explorer://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling". This helped me to get away with the song details popup next to volume bar. But the volume bar still appears. Anyways works for me.

Comment: You can add your comment in the answer section.